# how to limit data inside foreach value if there is condition applied?

Tags: php, laravel

In my blade template, I have applied foreach loop . And the data from foreach loop is from relation that I want to show. In that single loop I have to show three different type of data by applying IF condition. From my backend i have passed whole collection without limiting or pagination to front. And i want to limit data in my blade template.

```
blade view

@foreach($ft->menus as $menu)
    @if($menu->foodtype_id == $ft->id)
            //want to limti data here 
            // for every food type i want to show 6 data
    @endif
@endforeach
```

controller page

```
$data['food_type'] = FoodType::with('menus')->get();
```

Comment: so what issue are you having?

Comment: @lagbox i cannot limit data with condition i have given there. I want to show 6 data with each ($menu->foodtype_id == $ft->id)

Comment: "show 6 data" what ... what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly, you want to show 6 relationship rows for each food type. you have to check for current key in the loop then.

```
@foreach ($data['food_type'] as $ft)
    @foreach ($ft->menus as $key => $menu)
        @if ($key < 6)
            {{ $menu->attribute }}
        @else
            @break
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

this will show you the first six rows from the relationship. and when it reaches the limit, it will break the foreach loop.

you can query the relationship too.

```
@foreach ($ft->menus()->limit(6)->get() as $menu)
    {{ $menu->attribute }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: As i have applied condition  (if($menu->foodtype_id == $ft->id)) i want 6 data for each food_type. There are 3 food type and i want 18 data in total. 6 for each food type

Comment: @aashishthapamagar when you are already looping the relationship, your current condition is useless.  updating my answer for you.